# XSLT/Xpath: How to find out that something is or isn´t in key (with if)?

Tags: if-statement, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have problem with my code in XSLT with if. I am using key function and there I find out if something is in the key or not.

```
    <xsl:key name="hlp" match="help" use="@id" />
    ...
    <xsl:if test="key('hlp', @some_id) !=''">
    ...
    </xsl:if>
```

That is correct it gives me what I want but how I can make opposite condition that @some_id isn´t in key hlp... I mean:

```
    <xsl:if test="key('hlp', @some_id) <!--is equal--> ''">
    ...
    </xsl:if>
```

Is there something like that in XSLT/XPath?

Comment: What exactly does "something is in the key or not" mean? Being in key or out of key is a musical term, not an XSLT term. Please provide a better explanation of your question, preferably with examples of your condition being true and false.

Comment: P.S. The opposite of a known condition is `not($condition)`. Beware of the difference between `x != y` and `not(x = y)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `key('x', 'y')`, the result is the set of nodes in which the key is equal to `'y'`. You can test whether a node-set is empty using the empty() function (in XSLT 2.0) or the not() function in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:if test="not(key('x', 'y'))" version="1.0">...</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="empty(key('x', 'y'))" version="2.0">...</xsl:if>
```

or for the inverse test (to test if something was found):

```
<xsl:if test="key('x', 'y')" version="1.0">...</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="exists(key('x', 'y'))" version="2.0">...</xsl:if>
```

Testing by comparing the result against a string is wrong. The tests `key('x','y')=''` and `key('x','y')!=''` will both return false if the result of the `key()` function is an empty node-set; conversely, if the `key()` function selects two nodes, one with content and the other without, then both tests will return true.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:key name="hlp" match="help" use="@id" />
> ...
> <xsl:if test="key('hlp', @some_id) !=''">
> ...
> </xsl:if>
> ```

As already pointed by Michael Kay, avoid using the `!=` operator unless truly knowing what it does.

This aside (and the fact that the `key()` function returns a node-set), it is more in the spirit of XSLT to write the above as:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('hlp', @some_id)"/>
```

> but how I can make opposite condition that @some_id isn´t in key
>   hlp... I mean:
>
> ````
>     <xsl:if test="key('hlp', @some_id) <!--is equal--> ''">
>     ...
>     </xsl:if> ```
>
> Is there something like that in XSLT/XPath?
> ````

Again, in the spirit of XSLT I recommend using code like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/*[not(key('hlp', @some_id))]" mode="not-found"/>
```

In the `select` expression above one can substitute `/*` with any existing node in the document -- if this really matters.